# Make an active icon a link once activated, not a link if not activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a bootstrap template I found online to create a simple multi-step form. The template has some icons across the top that identify where the user is in the form completion process. Once they complete the form step and select the next button, the icon map at the top advances to the next step and the previous step is now activated (color changed).

I want to be able to make these icons an active link once the user has completed the step so they can quickly navigate back to a previous step by clicking on the icon. How can I make the icons an active link to their associated steps once they have been activated. Below is my html and js and jsfiddle link.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <!-- Top content -->
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-box">
          <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="f1">

            <h3>Register To Our App</h3>
            <p>Fill in the form to get instant access</p>
            <div class="f1-steps">
              <div class="f1-progress">
                <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="16.66" data-number-of-steps="3" style="width: 16.66%;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-step active">
                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                <p>about</p>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-step">
                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                <p>account</p>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-step">
                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
                <p>social</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <fieldset>
              <h4>Tell us who you are:</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-first-name">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-first-name" placeholder="First name..." class="f1-first-name form-control" id="f1-first-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-last-name">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-last-name" placeholder="Last name..." class="f1-last-name form-control" id="f1-last-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-about-yourself">About yourself</label>
                <textarea name="f1-about-yourself" placeholder="About yourself..." class="f1-about-yourself form-control" id="f1-about-yourself"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
              <h4>Set up your account:</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-email" placeholder="Email..." class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="f1-password" placeholder="Password..." class="f1-password form-control" id="f1-password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-repeat-password">Repeat password</label>
                <input type="password" name="f1-repeat-password" placeholder="Repeat password..." class="f1-repeat-password form-control" id="f1-repeat-password">
              </div>
              <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
              <h4>Social media profiles:</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-facebook">Facebook</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-facebook" placeholder="Facebook..." class="f1-facebook form-control" id="f1-facebook">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-twitter">Twitter</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-twitter" placeholder="Twitter..." class="f1-twitter form-control" id="f1-twitter">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-google-plus">Google plus</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-google-plus" placeholder="Google plus..." class="f1-google-plus form-control" id="f1-google-plus">
              </div>
              <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function scroll_to_class(element_class, removed_height) {
  var scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - removed_height;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: scroll_to
    }, 0);
  }
}

function bar_progress(progress_line_object, direction) {
  var number_of_steps = progress_line_object.data('number-of-steps');
  var now_value = progress_line_object.data('now-value');
  var new_value = 0;
  if (direction == 'right') {
    new_value = now_value + (100 / number_of_steps);
  } else if (direction == 'left') {
    new_value = now_value - (100 / number_of_steps);
  }
  progress_line_object.attr('style', 'width: ' + new_value + '%;').data('now-value', new_value);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  /*
      Form
  */
  $('.f1 fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');

  $('.f1 input[type="text"], .f1 input[type="password"], .f1 textarea').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
  });

  // next step
  $('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
        next_step = false;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
    });
    // fields validation

    if (next_step) {
      parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
        // change icons
        current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
        // progress bar
        bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
        // show next step
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
        // scroll window to beginning of the form
        scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
      });
    }

  });

  // previous step
  $('.f1 .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
      // change icons
      current_active_step.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active');
      // progress bar
      bar_progress(progress_line, 'left');
      // show previous step
      $(this).prev().fadeIn();
      // scroll window to beginning of the form
      scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
    });
  });

  // submit
  $('.f1').on('submit', function(e) {

    // fields validation
    $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
    });
    // fields validation

  });


});
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/93r5y1g3/2/

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, is there something more I could have done?

Comment: Sorry, I am just now getting back to this. Yes, it helped. I am new to js and jQuery, so a quick question... so if i want to have the icons (once activated) navigate to the associated step, you mentioned to add an identifier to the fieldset. So, I can add something like <fieldset id="aboutInfo"> to the first one, >fieldset id="acctInfo"> to the 2nd and <fieldset id="socialInfo"> to the last. Now, how do I go about using js to get the links to work when they are activated but not when they have not been activated? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman Hello, just wanted to check and see if you had a chance to read my response comment and had any advice. Thank you again.

Comment: sorry about that. Had a baby, so I've been offline for a couple weeks. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Added an updated example. If this works for you, go ahead and select it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't make the icons links, because based on your current workflow, you don't want to actually navigate to a different page. You just want to execute some javascript.

Instead, add `cursor: pointer;` to the css for items that are clickable, and add an event listener for `click` events on eligible icons.

Here I've added the cursor change when hovering over a clickable icon. 
https://jsfiddle.net/93r5y1g3/4/

It just sets the following in css:

```
.f1-step.activated > .f1-step-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Regarding the actual change between fieldsets, it looks like you're doing relative moves only. Your code fades out the parent fieldset of the button that was clicked and fades in the `next()`. If you are going to permit jumping between steps, you'll need to make two significant changes:

1. You need each fieldset to have an identifier that is referenced from the icon (so that when you click an icon you can find the related fieldset).
2. You need to add an event listener for "click" events on each icon that you want to allow users to click. It may be easiest to add the listener to all icons onload, and then have your function just return false if the user isn't allowed to click the icon.

Hope this helps.

**edit:**

I've updated the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/93r5y1g3/8/) with a working example of jumping between fieldsets. You can only jump to active fieldsets.

Here's what I changed:

1. Added `id` tags to each fieldset.
2. Added `data-fieldset` to the icons so that each icon can be linked to a fieldset.
3. Added a simple event listener to change the active icons and fieldsets when an icon is clicked. Note that if an icon is clicked that hasn't been activated, nothing happens.

Here's the listener:

```
// Go to step
$('.f1-step-icon').on('click', function(e){
  var current_step = {
      fieldset: $($(".f1-step.active").children('.f1-step-icon').data('fieldset')),
      circle: $(".f1-step.active")
  }
  var jump_to_step = {
      fieldset: $($(this).data('fieldset')),
      circle: $(this).parent()
  }
  if (! jump_to_step.circle.hasClass("activated")) {
      // Right now, this prevents users jumping forward.
      // If you want jumping forward to be allowed, you need to add
      // some logic to leave a step unfinished and force a return to it.
      return;
  }
  current_step.fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
    current_step.circle.removeClass('active').addClass('activated')
    jump_to_step.circle.addClass('active');
    jump_to_step.fieldset.fadeIn();
    scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
  });
});
```